# Replace Hard Drive for an SSD - Suggestion?

Tags: ssd, hard-disk, osx

I have a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012), and I'd like to speed up my computer. To do this, I'd like to change my Hard Drive for an SSD (with approximately 500 GB memory). I thought buying an SSD PCI Express (those used at Apple), but I don't know if this what is best.

**Question :** Could anyone be able to suggest me a very good SSD for my computer?

**Question :** What is the better choice between an SSD PCI Express and the [OWC
480GB Mercury Extreme® Pro 6G SSD 2.5" Serial-ATA 7mm Solid State Drive](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/SSD7P6G480/) ?

Comment: This is actually a very easy question to answer; there's no reason it should be on hold.  Your MBP **cannot** accept SSD PCIe, just regular 2.5" SATA SSDs.  I have personally updated MBPs and iMacs with [Samsung 850 EVO SSD](https://goo.gl/oMa2hj) with excellent results.  Personally, I would stay away from OWC - they are just overy expensive for what they do and reliability is questionable.  Also, you may have some better luck viewing this post, [My Macbook Is Slow](http://bit.ly/2dnMvrZ), over on Ask Different

Comment: Thank you very much @DigitalBoffin, I appreciate! I think It is possible to install SSD PCIe. When you go to About this Mac -> System Report -> PCI, they explain that "This computer doesn't contain any PCI cards or devices. If you installed or connected, a PCI card or device, make sure they’re properly installed." So it is somehow possible to install an SSD PCIe.

Comment: I **guarantee** that you can't install a PCIe SSD.  While your logic board has a PCIe bus, there are no slots for you to use.  Have a look at this [iFixit.com](http://bit.ly/2dfO2gs) document on replacing the drive and for more details.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comment. Do you know if the Samsung 850 EVO SSD is compatible with my MBP?

Comment: It's fully compatible.

Comment: Ok, but when you look at the product, we realize it is only compatible with Windows 10/8/7/Vista SP1 and above (32/64 bit), Windows Server 2008 (32/64 bit), Linux Compatible. Are you sure it is compatible with my MBP?

Comment: Drives are non are not OS specific.  This one just comes from the factory *formatted* for Windows.  You can format a drive to work in any computer - OS X, Linux, or Windows